# How to render output of cartridge API's on custom HTML page?

Tags: python, html, django, mezzanine, cartridge

I am working on a cartridge project. I have created custom html templates for better visual and now I want to render all data which is coming through cartridge's built in APIs on my custom html pages. For.ex. I have a product.html, on which I want to show all products stored in db (category wise).

Actually, I tried to explore url,

```
url("^shop/", include("cartridge.shop.urls")),
```

I am not getting that on which API or Function, this url is hitting.

urls.py file of shop app looks like this, I tested it, none of those url get called,

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf.urls import url
from mezzanine.conf import settings

from cartridge.shop import views


_slash = "/" if settings.APPEND_SLASH else ""

urlpatterns = [
    url("^product/(?P<slug>.*)%s$" % _slash, views.product,
        name="shop_product"),
    url("^wishlist%s$" % _slash, views.wishlist,     name="shop_wishlist"),
    url("^cart%s$" % _slash, views.cart, name="shop_cart"),
    url("^checkout%s$" % _slash, views.checkout_steps, name="shop_checkout"),
    url("^checkout/complete%s$" % _slash, views.complete,
        name="shop_complete"),
    url("^invoice/(?P<order_id>\d+)%s$" % _slash, views.invoice,
        name="shop_invoice"),
    url("^invoice/(?P<order_id>\d+)/resend%s$" % _slash,
         views.invoice_resend_email, name="shop_invoice_resend"),
]
```

These are cartridge's views for '/shop/product', '/shop/wishlist' and '/shop/cart'

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from future.builtins import int, str

from json import dumps

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.messages import info
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from mezzanine.conf import settings
from mezzanine.utils.importing import import_dotted_path
from mezzanine.utils.views import set_cookie, paginate
from mezzanine.utils.urls import next_url

from cartridge.shop import checkout
from cartridge.shop.forms import (AddProductForm, CartItemFormSet,
                                  DiscountForm, OrderForm)
from cartridge.shop.models import Product, ProductVariation, Order
from cartridge.shop.models import DiscountCode
from cartridge.shop.utils import recalculate_cart, sign

try:
    from xhtml2pdf import pisa
except (ImportError, SyntaxError):
    pisa = None
HAS_PDF = pisa is not None


# Set up checkout handlers.
handler = lambda s: import_dotted_path(s) if s else lambda *args: None
billship_handler = handler(settings.SHOP_HANDLER_BILLING_SHIPPING)
tax_handler = handler(settings.SHOP_HANDLER_TAX)
payment_handler = handler(settings.SHOP_HANDLER_PAYMENT)
order_handler = handler(settings.SHOP_HANDLER_ORDER)


def product(request, slug, template="shop/product.html",
            form_class=AddProductForm, extra_context=None):
    """
    Display a product - convert the product variations to JSON as well as
    handling adding the product to either the cart or the wishlist.
    """
    published_products = Product.objects.published(for_user=request.user)
    product = get_object_or_404(published_products, slug=slug)
    fields = [f.name for f in ProductVariation.option_fields()]
    variations = product.variations.all()
    variations_json = dumps([dict([(f, getattr(v, f))
        for f in fields + ["sku", "image_id"]]) for v in variations])
    to_cart = (request.method == "POST" and
               request.POST.get("add_wishlist") is None)
    initial_data = {}
    if variations:
        initial_data = dict([(f, getattr(variations[0], f)) for f in fields])
    initial_data["quantity"] = 1
    add_product_form = form_class(request.POST or None, product=product,
                                  initial=initial_data, to_cart=to_cart)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if add_product_form.is_valid():
            if to_cart:
                quantity = add_product_form.cleaned_data["quantity"]
                request.cart.add_item(add_product_form.variation, quantity)
                recalculate_cart(request)
                info(request, _("Item added to cart"))
                return redirect("shop_cart")
            else:
                skus = request.wishlist
                sku = add_product_form.variation.sku
                if sku not in skus:
                    skus.append(sku)
                info(request, _("Item added to wishlist"))
                response = redirect("shop_wishlist")
                set_cookie(response, "wishlist", ",".join(skus))
                return response
    related = []
    if settings.SHOP_USE_RELATED_PRODUCTS:
        related = product.related_products.published(for_user=request.user)
    context = {
        "product": product,
        "editable_obj": product,
        "images": product.images.all(),
        "variations": variations,
        "variations_json": variations_json,
        "has_available_variations": any([v.has_price() for v in variations]),
        "related_products": related,
        "add_product_form": add_product_form
    }
    context.update(extra_context or {})
    templates = [u"shop/%s.html" % str(product.slug), template]
    return TemplateResponse(request, templates, context)

@never_cache
def wishlist(request, template="shop/wishlist.html",
             form_class=AddProductForm, extra_context=None):
    """
    Display the wishlist and handle removing items from the wishlist and
    adding them to the cart.
    """

    if not settings.SHOP_USE_WISHLIST:
        raise Http404

    skus = request.wishlist
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        to_cart = request.POST.get("add_cart")
        add_product_form = form_class(request.POST or None,
                                      to_cart=to_cart)
        if to_cart:
            if add_product_form.is_valid():
                request.cart.add_item(add_product_form.variation, 1)
                recalculate_cart(request)
                message = _("Item added to cart")
                url = "shop_cart"
            else:
                error = list(add_product_form.errors.values())[0]
        else:
            message = _("Item removed from wishlist")
            url = "shop_wishlist"
        sku = request.POST.get("sku")
        if sku in skus:
            skus.remove(sku)
        if not error:
            info(request, message)
            response = redirect(url)
            set_cookie(response, "wishlist", ",".join(skus))
            return response

    # Remove skus from the cookie that no longer exist.
    published_products = Product.objects.published(for_user=request.user)
    f = {"product__in": published_products, "sku__in": skus}
    wishlist = ProductVariation.objects.filter(**f).select_related("product")
    wishlist = sorted(wishlist, key=lambda v: skus.index(v.sku))
    context = {"wishlist_items": wishlist, "error": error}
    context.update(extra_context or {})
    response = TemplateResponse(request, template, context)
    if len(wishlist) < len(skus):
        skus = [variation.sku for variation in wishlist]
        set_cookie(response, "wishlist", ",".join(skus))
    return response


@never_cache
def cart(request, template="shop/cart.html",
         cart_formset_class=CartItemFormSet,
         discount_form_class=DiscountForm,
         extra_context=None):
    """
    Display cart and handle removing items from the cart.
    """
    cart_formset = cart_formset_class(instance=request.cart)
    discount_form = discount_form_class(request, request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        valid = True
        if request.POST.get("update_cart"):
            valid = request.cart.has_items()
            if not valid:
                # Session timed out.
                info(request, _("Your cart has expired"))
            else:
                cart_formset = cart_formset_class(request.POST,
                                                  instance=request.cart)
                valid = cart_formset.is_valid()
                if valid:
                    cart_formset.save()
                    recalculate_cart(request)
                    info(request, _("Cart updated"))
                else:
                    # Reset the cart formset so that the cart
                    # always indicates the correct quantities.
                    # The user is shown their invalid quantity
                    # via the error message, which we need to
                    # copy over to the new formset here.
                    errors = cart_formset._errors
                    cart_formset = cart_formset_class(instance=request.cart)
                    cart_formset._errors = errors
        else:
            valid = discount_form.is_valid()
            if valid:
                discount_form.set_discount()
            # Potentially need to set shipping if a discount code
            # was previously entered with free shipping, and then
            # another was entered (replacing the old) without
            # free shipping, *and* the user has already progressed
            # to the final checkout step, which they'd go straight
            # to when returning to checkout, bypassing billing and
            # shipping details step where shipping is normally set.
            recalculate_cart(request)
        if valid:
            return redirect("shop_cart")
    context = {"cart_formset": cart_formset}
    context.update(extra_context or {})
    settings.use_editable()
    if (settings.SHOP_DISCOUNT_FIELD_IN_CART and
            DiscountCode.objects.active().exists()):
        context["discount_form"] = discount_form
    return TemplateResponse(request, template, context)
```

Comment: If you just want to customize the template, I don't understand what views have to do with it. Just copy the relevant template from cartridge to the same path in your templates and modify it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit **shop** url, your application will try to use an empty url from your cartridge.shop.urls file. So basically when you would like to check which API / view is called, go to this file and look for something similar to this:

```
url(r'^$', 'your-view', name='your-view'),
```

ok after posting your second urls file you have following options:

you call:

1. /shop/wishlist/ - you are executing a view named **wishlist**
2. /shop/cart/ - you are executing a view named **cart**
3. /shop/checkout/complete/ - you are executing a view named **complete**

so just find your views.py file, and all those views are going to be there

Comment: I checked that also, I open urls.py file of shop app and it contains 5 url() instances in urlpatterns. but, I tested all of those thoroughly, none of those get called.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your urls file ?

Comment: I posted it.you can check now.

Comment: When I click on shop button on navbar of cartridge, I am getting following request header:                                                                               Request URL:http://localhost:8000/shop/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000     and this url shows me all products on page. I want to know that from which api I am getting those all products on shop page, because its calling just '/shop/' nothing after that.

Comment: Show us your views then

Comment: I have added views.